# mvc3: Binding a datetime in a localized application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, localization, model-binding

I have an MVC3 application that supports multiple languages.

Do I need to create a custom binder in order to bind a DateTime field using the correct locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, assuming that you set proper `CultureInfo` on `Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture` and `Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture` and you always post datetimes in this culture.

Comment: D'oh!  Apparently the MVC framework isn't smart enough to realize that setting a LANG session variable means it should automagically set the Thread cultures :)